# Changing global integer variable from inside function scope

Tags: python-3.x

I want to have a global variable changed form inside a function. The global variable is an integer. I am getting an error when trying to do so. This is a simplified version of what I am trying to do:

```
variable = 3


def test():

    b = 5
    if b > 0:
        variable -= 1
        print(variable)
    else:
        print('fail')


test()
```

Can anyone help me in finding a way to reduce the integer variable by 1 every time the function test runs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When referring to a variable that's outside of a function that you don't pass in as a parameter, you must declare it as global before referencing it. Add `global variable` to the beginning of your function and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

```
variable = 3
def test():
  b = 5
  global variable
  variable -= 1
  if b > 0:
    print(variable)
  else:
    print('fail')
test()
test()
test()
test()
test()
test()
```

output:

2
1
0
-1
-2
-3

Note that the condition will not satisfy to fail because we are not doing anything with b that is equals to 5 forever.